# Is it possible to remove iOS Quicktype Keyboard but keep auto correction?

Tags: ios, uikeyboard

I know it is possible to remove the QuickType keyboard of a UITextView or UITextField, by using `.autoCorrectionType = .No` , but this also disables auto-correct and autocompletion while the user is typing.
Is there a possible work around to this?
I'm trying to make a very clean note making app and have an accessory to the keyboard, that looks ugly with the quicktype bit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you are asking. Is possible but even if it were - is that a good idea?
You may not like how it looks but allot of people really like that feature and might not like it if you remove it. 
Users who don't like that can turn it off in the phone's settings so if your user does have it - there is a good reason to keep it there